# how can i solve this error " Error: The control character U+0000 can only be used in strings and comments."

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

[image: screenshot]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:realshop/screens/product_overview_screen.dart';

    void main(){
    runApp(MyApp());
    }
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple),
        home: ProductOverviewScreen(),
        //routes: {},
        );
     }
   }
```

Comment: From you debug console, it seems like the problem is in line 20, column 2. Try check what character is there, might be a typo.

Comment: there is not a character in this line  and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

first restart your windows/ device
if a problem still exist , you should upgrade flutter then restart your device and it will be solved.

Comment: didn't work for me